# How to make sysctl network bridge settings persist after a reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, nat, kvm-virtualization, multicast, sysctl

I am setting up a notebook for software demo purpose.  The machine has 8GB RAM, a Core i7 Intel CPU, a 128GB SSD, and runs Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit. The notebook is used as a KVM host and runs a few KVM guests.

All such guests use the `virbr0` default bridge. To enable them to communicate with each other using multicast, I added the following to the host's `/etc/sysctl.conf`, as shown below

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
```

Afterwards, following `man sysctl(8)`, I issued the following:

```
sudo /sbin/sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

My understanding is that this should make these settings persist over reboots.  I tested it, and was surprised to find out the following:

```
root@sdn1 :/proc/sys/net/bridge# more *tables
::::::::::::::
bridge-nf-call-arptables
::::::::::::::
1
::::::::::::::
bridge-nf-call-ip6tables
::::::::::::::
1
::::::::::::::
bridge-nf-call-iptables
::::::::::::::
1
```

All defaults are coming back!

Yes. I can use some kludgy "get arounds" such as putting a `/sbin/sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf` into the host's `/etc/rc.local` but I would rather "do it right".  Did I misunderstand the man page or is there something that I missed?

Thanks for any hints.

-- Zack

Comment: If it's not applying sysctl.conf directives, you likely broke something.

Comment: Actually, I found the answer in another Q: http://serverfault.com/questions/270201/sysctl-conf-not-running-on-boot.  It's actually a long standing Debian bug since at least 2006 and Ubuntu has inherited it by being a derivative. I will use my "kludge" approach as a get around for now.

Comment: Ah, somebody else broke something. Somehow not surprised that it's not fixed yet.....

Comment: Regretably, just tried it. Even putting `/sbin/sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf` into `/etc/rc.local` didn't help. Even with a `while` loop! :-(  So, Still searching for a "work-around".

Answer (score 6):

I also have this problem on Ubuntu 14.04.1

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
```

Are not set on reboot!!!

I have to manually do:

`sudo brctl show`

`sudo sysctl -p`

Only then the parameters are set?!

This is so frustrating. I'm setting up a HA system and I need net.bridge.X set on reboot!!!

---

So I think I found a solution...

It appears there's some conflicts with ufw.

Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and comment out:

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
```

Edit `/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf` and append this lines to the end (note the slashes, rather than the dots...):

```
net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
```

reboot the machine, and everything works as expected.